# how to test out lockings in postgres

Tags: postgresql

There are different types of locks in postgres, we use locks in parallel request to say prevent unwanted rows or data in general to be read/written.

Say I want to test out different combination of lockings that I have setup for queries. For e.g. `select * from mytable where age > 12 and age < 45 for update`; or similar other locks.

say I bombard my psql database with 1000 requests, are there any tools that generate a report that tell me different stats pertaining to these locks?

- on request I a lock was encountered, The lock kept this transaction waiting for x seconds, the lock was on rows xyz , the cost of the lock etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) to inspect locks used by ongoing transactions. You can find [a few examples](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) at postgresql wiki page. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/KOm6zl3I)

| datname | relation | query | query_start | age | transactionid | mode | granted | usename | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | pg_locks | SELECT a.datname, l.relation::regclass, a.query, a.query_start, age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age", l.transactionid, l.mode, l.GRANTED, a.usename, a.pid FROM pg_stat_activity a JOIN pg_locks l ON l.pid = a.pid ORDER BY a.query_start; | 2023-10-09 09:30:30.221477+00 | 00:00:00 | *null* | AccessShareLock | t | postgres | 786 |

It's a live view, not a logging table but there are [lock management settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-locks.html) and [logging parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LOCK-WAITS) you can tweak to get PostgreSQL to put that info into the server log:

```
LOG: process 663 still waiting for ExclusiveLock on advisory lock [233136,1,2,2] after 1000.365 ms
DETAIL: Process holding the lock: 660. Wait queue: 663.
STATEMENT: SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1, 2);
```

```
LOG: process 583 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on relation 185044 of database 16384 after 2175.443 ms
STATEMENT: ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN y text;
```

There are also external tools like [PgMonitor](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/postgres-locking-when-is-it-concerning) and [pganalyze](https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/locks) that you can use to analyze locking behaviour on your db. Log entry examples above are actually from the [pganalyze blog](https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-lock-monitoring-lwlock-log-lock-waits) on the topic.